# invalid conversion from throwing function of type - swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using `URLRequest` but I got this error:

```
invalid conversion from throwing function of type...
```

[image]

my code:

```
func getFirstPageApplication(EMPTY:String,completionHandler: @escaping (_ response: AnyObject) -> ())
{
    var strResponse = "null"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: self.baseURL+"getFirstPageApplication")!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let postString = "EMAIL=\(EMPTY)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
    { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        do {
            let json:AnyObject? = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = json{
                print(parseJSON)
            }
            completionHandler(parseJSON)
        }

    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
  let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            response({} as AnyObject)
                        }

                    } else {
                        if let usableData = data {
                            do {

                                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: usableData, options:
                                    JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                                print(jsonResult) //this part works fine
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    response(jsonResult as AnyObject)
                                }

                            } catch {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    response({} as AnyObject)
                                }
                                print("JSON Processing Failed")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I got this error: `use of unresolved identifier callback{}`

Comment: you need to just replace block name with your block name.

Comment: I think response should replace with `completionHandler`. yeah?

Comment: yes ..correct . you need to just replace completionHandler.